# Why is this NHibernate code performing a chain of explicit casts?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, casting

I was looking through the source of my NHibernate project (version 3.3.1.4000) and I just noticed something strange in the [AnywhereMatchMode](http://aqdweb.sourceforge.net/apis/doxy-latest/typeNHibernate_1_1Expression_1_1MatchMode.html) class:

```
public override string ToMatchString(string pattern)
{
    return (string) (object) '%' + (object) pattern + (string) (object) '%';
}
```

Why on earth would they cast a char to an object and immediately re-cast it to a string? Why cast a string to an object before adding it to other strings? Is there a performance bonus here, or an edge case to avoid? I'm looking for the idea behind this code, because there must be a reason for it.

**Note:** I just realized, I got here with ReSharper's ["Navigate To" feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Navigate_from_Here.html), so this may be decompiled code I'm looking at. Even if it is, I'd like to know what's going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it may just be an artifact of ReSharper's "Navigate To", looking at the source code for NHibernate that method looks like this:

```
public override string ToMatchString(string pattern)
{
    return '%' + pattern + '%';
}
```

[NHibernate Source Code](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/967091f5c22a16a576f46144055f78c0f373ffcd/src/NHibernate/Criterion/MatchMode.cs#L178)

Update: Here's the MSIL for this method:

```
.method public hidebysig virtual instance string 
        ToMatchString(string pattern) cil managed
{
  // Code size       26 (0x1a)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] string CS$1$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   37
  IL_0003:  box        [mscorlib]System.Char
  IL_0008:  ldarg.1
  IL_0009:  ldc.i4.s   37
  IL_000b:  box        [mscorlib]System.Char
  IL_0010:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object,
                                                              object,
                                                              object)
  IL_0015:  stloc.0
  IL_0016:  br.s       IL_0018
  IL_0018:  ldloc.0
  IL_0019:  ret
} // end of method AnywhereMatchMode::ToMatchString
```

Since the code compiles the string concatenation to the optimized `string.Concat("%", pattern, "%")`, when Resharper decompiles it looks like it may be representing the boxing as a cast to `object`.

Comment: I suspected as much, but does that mean all these conversions are happening in the MSIL? Any idea why?

Comment: Updated to include the MSIL for the method.